# Annotating a function literal's implicit argument with a type

Tags: function, scala, literals, implicit, type-parameter

How do I annotate the argument of a function literal with a type if I want that argument to be implicit?

```
trait Test { def call[C, T](fun: C => T): T }

def test1(t: Test): Unit =
  t.call { c: Int => 33 } // ok

def test2(t: Test): Unit =
  t.call { implicit c => 33 } // type missing...

def test3(t: Test): Unit =
  t.call { (implicit c: Int) => 33 } // not possible...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.8.0 introduced implicit params for function literals. But the syntax was limited, as you have found, to a single parameter without type annotation.

A single typed argument can be used in Scala 2.9.0.

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/test/files/pos/t3672.scala?rev=23288

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/23289

They aren't yet handled by the IntelliJ Parser, though: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2441

Comment: Good news, looking forward to 2.9.0.final!